# c# WebClient problem using a URL with URL-encoded cyrillic chars

Tags: c#, webclient

I'm tryinig to load a file from a web server with a request URL that contains a parameter with cyrillic chars.
But I'm not getting this to work in c#, even if I URL-Encode the param.

When I open the page in IE with
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q=ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ
the server does not respond.

Using the URL-encoded version
http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q=%d0%97%d0%94%d0%a0%d0%90%d0%92%d0%a1%d0%a2%d0%92%d0%a3%d0%99%d0%a2%d0%95
the server responds as expected.

Now my problem:
I want to download the MP3 from C# ...

```
var url = string.Format("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q={0}", 
          Server.UrlEncode("ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ"));
System.Net.WebClient client = new WebClient(); 
var res = client.DownloadData(url);
```

And this does NOT work with cyrillic chars. I always get a zero-byte answer, like the first, non-encoded request.
When I send "normal" chars, the code above works fine.

So ... I'm doing something wrong.
Any hints? Tipps? Solutions?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the user-agent for the `WebClient` - this works:

```
string url = "http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?tl=ru&q=ЗДРАВСТВУЙТЕ";
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Headers.Add("user-agent", 
                   "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
var res = client.DownloadData(url);
```

From the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx):

> A WebClient instance does not send
>   optional HTTP headers by default. If
>   your request requires an optional
>   header, you must add the header to the
>   Headers collection. For example, to
>   retain queries in the response, you
>   must add a user-agent header. Also,
>   servers may return 500 (Internal
>   Server Error) if the user agent header
>   is missing.

Comment: Works great, thanks. Just for me to understand: Why do I need the user-agent, when I'm sending a cyrillic-URL and for a latin-URL not?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
```

I don't use user-agent header but for me it works:

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
string response = client.DownloadString(_url);
```